# How to write c++ smartpointer for operator == / !=

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

In my project, I have some mechanism in my framework, so I have designed C++ smart-pointer myself.

But I encounter equality and inequality problem for smart-pointer.

```
class Ref {
public:
    void ref(){}
    void unref(){}
};

template<class T>
class SmartPtr
{
public:
    typedef T element_type;

    SmartPtr() : _ptr(nullptr) {}
    SmartPtr(T* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) { if (_ptr) _ptr->ref(); }
    SmartPtr(const SmartPtr& rp) : _ptr(rp._ptr)  { if (_ptr) _ptr->ref(); }

    template<class Other>
    SmartPtr(const SmartPtr<Other>& rp) : _ptr(rp._ptr)
    { if (_ptr) _ptr->ref(); }

    ~SmartPtr() { if (_ptr) _ptr->unref();  _ptr = 0; }

    SmartPtr& operator = (const SmartPtr& rp)
    {    assign(rp);    return *this;}

    template<class Other> SmartPtr& operator = (const SmartPtr<Other>& rp)
    {   assign(rp);    return *this;}
    template<class Other> void assign(const SmartPtr<Other>& rp) 
    {_ptr=rp._ptr;}

    operator T*() const { return _ptr; }

    template<class U>
    bool operator == (const SmartPtr<U>& rp) const
    { return (_ptr==rp._ptr); }

    template<class U>
    friend bool operator == (const U* ptr, const SmartPtr& rp)
    { return (ptr==rp._ptr); }

    template<class U>
    friend bool operator == (const SmartPtr& rp, const U* ptr)
    { return (ptr==rp._ptr); }

private:
    template<class U> friend class SmartPtr;
    T* _ptr;
};
```

The code failed when I writing following code :

```
class A : public Ref {};
class B : public A {};
SmartPtr<A> a1 = new A;
A* a2 = a1;
bool flag = a1==a2;  // ambiguous error, error message follows

SmartPtr<B> b = new B;
SmartPtr<A> a3 = b;
bool flag2 = a3==b;  // build pass
```

compilation error message

```
maybe "bool operator ==<A>(const U *,const ECB::SmartPtr<A> &)"
or    "bool operator ==<A>(const U *,const ECB::SmartPtr<B> &)"
or    "built-in C++ operator==(T1, T1)"
or    "built-in C++ operator==(A *SmartPtr<A>::* , A *SmartPtr<A>::* )"
```

How to modify the template SmartPtr class to avoid the ambiguous errors ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 This is an intrusive smart pointer, so somewhat different from the `std` smart pointers.

Comment: @MaxLanghof oh I see, then my comment is rather off-topic i guess ;)

Comment: Implicit conversions seem so convenient, but they are pure evil. Don't allow them.

Comment: You may want `explicit SmartPtr(T* ptr)` instead. Not only to fix this problem, but to avoid accidentally taking ownership of something you don't intend to `unref`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That does not fix the problem. They would need to make the conversion operator explicit.

Comment: For conveniently, I want to use ```SmartPtr<A> a = new B;```, is there some ways to pass the compilation error while not using  ```explicit SmartPtr(T* ptr) ```?

Comment: @molbdnilo I believe this is a pattern that originates from published idea/source and isn't something that people think of on the spot. I've seen this same concept elsewhere, and while I find it deeply convoluted and unsafe (which may just be due to being used to the `std::` smart pointers), I've seen it implemented almost exactly like this (including all the worrysome implicit conversions) elsewhere before.

Comment: @Laine You can just write `SmartPtr<A> a(new B);` (or curly braces).

Comment: @MaxLanghof All bad ideas have been published, used, and copied many times; that's how their lack of goodness is discovered. I used to cherish convenience myself, but you can only shoot yourself in the foot so many times before you start thinking that not doing it is perhaps the more convenient solution after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling with gcc, you get a clearer error message:

```
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
       bool flag = a1==a2;
                       ^~
note: candidate 1: 'bool operator==(const SmartPtr<T>&, const U*) [with U = A; T = A]'
    friend bool operator == (const SmartPtr& rp, const U* ptr)
                ^~~~~~~~
note: candidate 2: 'operator==(A*, A*)' <built-in>
```

There are two candidates. Your declaration of:

```cpp
template<class U>
friend bool operator == (const SmartPtr& rp, const U* ptr);
```

And the built in one that would be called by `a1.operator A*() == a2` (Comparing two pointers).

To use the first one, `U` would be deduced as `A`, but the parameter is still `const A*`, whilst your pointer is `A*`. In the second one, your smart pointer will have to be converted to a regular pointer using the user-defined conversion (`operator T*()`).

In both cases, there is a conversion (Even though the user defined conversion is usually worse than `A*` to `const A*` conversion).

The problem is, when considering the first argument (the smart pointer), your friend operator is the better match. But for the second argument, the built-in one is the better match. GCC overcomes this by using the logic that "user-defined conversion operators is a worse conversion than `A*` to `const A*`", but this is a non-standard extension (And goes away with [`-pedantic`](https://godbolt.org/z/rHRKR5)).

A fix is to have a non-const overload too:

```
template<class U>
friend bool operator == (const SmartPtr& rp, U* ptr)
{ return (ptr==rp._ptr); }
```

(And you can remove the const overload, since `U` can be deduced as `const A` in that case)

Comment: Note that MSVC actually gives the best additional information here:  `note: qualification adjustment (const/volatile) may be causing the ambiguity` https://godbolt.org/z/0bfcZY

Comment: Also, you don't need the non-const overload **too** I think - you **only** need the non-const overload. The `const U*` case is handled by the implicit conversion to `T*` (I think?).